# Vert.x file upload not working as expected

Tags: file, file-upload, multipart, vert.x

I am trying to implement an endpoint to accept files like pdf/txt and save it in local file share. I enabled the multipart by doing:

```
router.route("/*").handler(BodyHandler.create()).setUploadsDirectory("/sample/dir").

router.route(HttpMethod.POST,"/v2/upload/")
            .produces(APPLICATION_JSON)
            .handler(this::uploadDocument);
```

In uploadDocument i have this code:

```
private void uploadDocument(RoutingContext rc) {

    LOGGER.info("In Route uploadDocument");

    for (FileUpload f : rc.fileUploads()) {
        System.out.println("f"+f.fileName);

    }

    rc.response().end();
}
```

But `rc.fileUploads` is empty somehow.This is not enabling me to implement fileUpload using vert.x

Vert.x version - 3.3.3

Comment: Could you try something like this `router.route(HttpMethod.POST,"/v2/upload/").handler(BodyHandler.create()).produces(APPLICATION_JSON).handler(this::uploadDocument)` and see if this work any better

Comment: Does this compile? The first line should be `router.route().handler(BodyHandler.create().setUploadsDirectory("uploads"));`